# Jquery droppable accept

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

in my new project i used Jquery draggable and droppable function.
In droppable function i try add accept function. In this function i need to check id draged element.

```
 $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: function (event, ui){
            var dragShipType = parseInt($(ui.draggable).attr('id')[4], 10);
            ...
        },
```

when i run this code i can`t drag any draggable element.
But if somthing like

> var dragShipType = 4;

is ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLhn4/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LLhn4/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: function (ui){
        var dragShipType = parseInt($(ui.draggable).attr('id')[4], 10);
        ...
    },
```

don't know still someone is looking for answer, above is working :)